# Meta links in the footer on stackexchange sites

Tags: feature-request, meta

The footer of webmasters.stackexchange.com goes like:

■ stackoverflow.com  ■ api/apps  ■ careers  ■ serverfault.com  ■ superuser.com  ■ **meta**  ■ area 51  ■ webapps  ■ gaming  ■ ubuntu  ■ webmasters  ■ cooking  ■ game development  ■ math  ■ photography  ■ stats  ■ tex  ■ english  ■ theoretical cs  ■ programmers  ■ unix

where **meta** link directs to meta.stackoverflow.com.  It should point to the corresponding/appropriate meta site.

(Same is the case with serverfault.com and I guess lot many other related sites).

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not really the intent of that link -- like Area 51, Meta Stack Overflow has special significance, it is the "Washington DC" or national capital meta:

https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/about

> The focus of this site is the content topic. **If the question is about the Stack Exchange engine in a general sense, it should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow instead.**

compare with

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

There is of course a link to the webmasters "local" meta on the top of every page and on most question pages in the sidebar.

Comment: Okay. I am sure if its intentional it must be well though of ... just slightly unintuitive for a beginner.

Comment: probably a legacy of the transition from SO to SE being the central hub recently...(beginner observation :) )